# How to detect HTML tags in text?

Tags: php, html, strpos

I want to see if `$text` value contains any HTML formatting, so I can adjust the PHPMailer email accordingly as either HTML or plain text. Text looses the line feeds, if seen as HTML.

```
$email_body="<p><b>This is html code</b></p>";
$text = htmlentities($email_body); 
if (strpos($text,"<b>") !== false) {
    echo " Found a b ";                
}
```

This does not find this.

Comment: I'd suggest you might be going about this backwards; instead of generating your html and then stripping tags out; perhaps you should start with just the text and then build the html depending on whether or not it's html or plain-text.

Comment: The text is coming from a form where the user can either enter in straight text or html text.I need to find out if it contains html code so I can tell the emailler to format the body correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to do this using regex via [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) or [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) but there is an easier way: Use [`strip_tags`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) and then compare the stripped value to the non-stripped value.

```
// Set a test array of mixed strings.
$email_body_array = array();
$email_body_array[] = "<p><b>This is html code.</b></p>";
$email_body_array[] = "This is plain text.";
$email_body_array[] = "This is a <b>bold</b> statement..";

// Now roll through the strings & test them.
foreach ($email_body_array as $email_body) {
  $email_body_stripped = strip_tags($email_body);
  $text = htmlentities($email_body); 
  if ($email_body !== $email_body_stripped) {
    echo "That has HTML!<br />";                
  }
  else {
    echo "Boring, plain old text.<br />";                
  }
}
```

This is the output of the above showing the concept in action:

> That has HTML!
>
> Boring, plain old text.
>
> That has HTML!